# Selenium in Python: how to click non-English link?

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink

I want to find a link by its text but it's written in non-English characters (Hebrew to be precise, if that matters). The "find_element_by_link_text('link_text')" method would have otherwise suited my needs, but here it fails. Any idea how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: The code does not compile with non-English characters.

Comment: Post the error message that you get (the full traceback).

Answer (score 0):

In the future you need to pastebin a representative snippet of your code, and certainly a traceback. I'm going to assume that when you say "the code does not compile" that you mean that you get an exception telling you you haven't declared an encoding.

You need a line at the top of your file that looks like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` or whatever encoding the literals you've put in your file are in.

Comment: @Julian: You can also use `This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enter your Hebrew search text in your code, as long as you tell the Python compiler what encoding you're using for the file. [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) describes how to do this. Basically, you need to put a "magic" comment as the first or second line of your source file, looking like this:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

You don't have to use `utf-8` either, just put whatever encoding you are using (as long as it's one that Python can decode).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll be sure to check that.